# Is doing mitzvos, specifically thought mitzvos, allowed in the bathroom?

Tags: torah-study, mitzvah, bathroom

It is brought down by various poskim that Torah study is forbidden in the bathroom, albeit it is a debate whether today’s bathrooms have the same status.

May one perform mitzvos in a bathroom? Specifically, in the case of the six constant mitzvos which are performed through thought, May one think about these in a bathroom?

Comment: Could you list which six "thought mitzvos" you are referring to?

Comment: FWIW, I don’t see how this a duplicate. One is about a Bracha (has Shem HasShem) and another is through thought. Perhaps extremely different scenarios, but surely related.